# How to get code coverage for unit and robelectric code coverage using Jacoco plugin?

Tags: android, unit-testing, code-coverage, android-testing, jacoco

I have been using the Jacoco plugin to get code coverage for my android project. Currently on executing the test using this command,

```
gradlew test jacocoTestReport
```

It runs only the robolectric and UI test. I want to run the Unit test and the robolectric test instead. 
Following is the task for Jacoco created inside build.gradle,

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ['test', 'createDebugCoverageReport']) {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }
    def fileFilter = [ '**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*' ]
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
    def mainSrc = "$project.projectDir/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    executionData = fileTree(dir: project.buildDir, includes: [
            'jacoco/test.exec', 'outputs/code-coverage/connected/*coverage.ec'
    ])
}
```

Is there any way we can achieve the code coverage for unit and robolectric test using Jacoco. Please help if you have any idea regarding this

Comment: Have you tried Espresso testing. OpenClover may help you.